# How to redirect to a ruby on rails controller that renders a react rails page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, react-rails

I have a button on my homepage that redirects to my controller:
`redirect_to edit_user_path(user, track: "homepage")`

I can see that the redirect works correctly because if I throw a pry inside the controller it'll freeze.

The edit action inside my users_controller renders a react page. I am using the react rails gem.

When I visit the users/:id/edit page it works properly but for whatever reason when I go thru the redirect it doesn't load properly.

```rb
# edit.html.erb
`<%= react_component("App", @data) %>`
```

```rb
# users_controller#edit
# GET users/:id/edit
def edit
  @tracking = params[:track] if params[:track].present?
  @data = {name: "steve", age: 33, track: @tracking}
end
```

It almost looks like all of the props are missing because the react developer tools says: "waiting for roots to load..."

Comment: What does the react code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a timing issue. The link I was using had turbolinks enabled. When I changed turbolinks to be false everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the redirect code wrong.
Can you try this in the redirection controller?

```
redirect_to edit_user_path(user, track: "homepage")
```

Use `redirect_to` instead of `return`

Comment: This is a good catch but this isn't actually the problem. I will make the proper edits above. Thanks